Swap to files not working
I have all my swap used (by Rust compiler) and it didn't grow despite I do have swapspace package installed.
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15Gi        12Gi       2.4Gi       1.8Gi       2.5Gi       2.6Gi
Swap:          2.0Gi       2.0Gi          0B

A little later in time:
$ swapon
NAME           TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/nvme0n1p2 partition   2G   2G   -2

How to make swap to files work? Do I need to edit /etc/swapspace.conf?
/etc/swapspace.conf:
# This file is part of Swapspace.
# 
# Swapspace is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
# 
# Swapspace is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
# 
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with swapspace; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301, USA


# Swap path: location where swapspace may create and delete swapfiles.  For
# security reasons this directory must be accessible to root and to root only.
#swappath="/var/lib/swapspace"

# Lower free-space threshold: if the percentage of free space drops below this
# number, additional swapspace is allocated
#lower_freelimit=20

# Upper free-space threshold: if the percentage of free space exceeds this
# number, swapspace will attempt to free up swapspace
#upper_freelimit=60

# Percentage of free space swapspace should aim for when adding swapspace.  This
# should fall somewhere between lower_freelimit and upper_freelimit.
#freetarget=30

# Smallest allowed size for individual swapfiles
#min_swapsize=4m

# Greatest allowed size for individual swapfiles
#max_swapsize=2t

# Duration (roughly in seconds) of the moratorium on swap allocation that is
# instated if disk space runs out, or the cooldown time after a new swapfile is
# successfully allocated before swapspace will consider deallocating swap space
# again.  The default cooldown period is about 10 minutes.
#cooldown=600

Also:
$ systemctl status swapspace.service 
● swapspace.service - Swapspace, a dynamic swap space manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/swapspace.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2024-04-06 12:25:27 IDT; 1 week 2 days ago
       Docs: man:swapspace(8)
   Main PID: 5007 (swapspace)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18672)
     Memory: 696.0K
        CPU: 56min 53.175s
     CGroup: /system.slice/swapspace.service
             └─5007 /usr/sbin/swapspace

Apr 15 22:57:50 victor swapspace[5007]: Error: Could not enable swapfile '1': Invalid argument
Apr 16 07:54:11 victor swapspace[2805427]: Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 6.6 GiB (7115493376 bytes)
Apr 16 07:54:11 victor swapspace[2805427]: no label, UUID=e4971b48-a25a-48bd-bba4-c612569f996a
Apr 16 07:54:11 victor swapspace[5007]: Error: Could not enable swapfile '1': Invalid argument
Apr 16 08:04:19 victor swapspace[2920343]: Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 6.1 GiB (6517428224 bytes)
Apr 16 08:04:19 victor swapspace[2920343]: no label, UUID=5e0ae6b7-9715-4882-8cda-51707e96fbaa
Apr 16 08:04:19 victor swapspace[5007]: Error: Could not enable swapfile '1': Invalid argument
Apr 16 08:14:26 victor swapspace[2939298]: Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 6.1 GiB (6539935744 bytes)
Apr 16 08:14:26 victor swapspace[2939298]: no label, UUID=1ba42fae-6106-450e-9d96-3cdc040c84c6
Apr 16 08:14:26 victor swapspace[5007]: Error: Could not enable swapfile '1': Invalid argument


I've added another log file to the question.

Apparently, OpenZFS currently does not support swap files, as outlines in this bug report.
The problem was solved by switching from ZFS to btrfs.
